# Ruby script works without threads, crashes with

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a script I'm using to transfer audio recordings from my Twilio account to S3. The network requests take a long time, so I thought I'd use threading to run several requests in parallel. A simplifed version of my non-threaded code looks like this:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
account_sid = 'sid'
auth_token = 'secret'
twilio_rest_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

recordings = twilio_rest_client.account.recordings.list(page_size: 2)

recordings.map do |recording|
  recording.mp3! do |file|
    path = recording.mp3.gsub('https://api.twilio.com/', '')
    puts path
    # add code to transfer to S3 here
  end
end
```

This works fine. When I add threading like this:

```
recordings.map do |recording|
  Thread.new do
    recording.mp3! do |file|
      path = recording.mp3.gsub('https://api.twilio.com/', '')
      puts path
      # add code to transfer to S3 here
    end
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

Sometimes it works, and sometimes I get different errors each time I run it, like

```
/Users/michael/.rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1452:in `begin_transport': undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

or

```
/Users/michael/.rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:212:in `write0': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

or

```
/Users/michael/.rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000
```

I've never used them before, so am I not using threads correctly? Or is this just an indicator that the `twilio-ruby` library isn't threadsafe?

Comment: I'm not familar with Twilio, but it appears that the rest client simply isn't thread-safe.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Hydra and [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus), which implement and handle parallel HTTP requests very nicely. I've used them to pull in multiple requests in parallel with good results; I think I was using 15 at once without problems.

Comment: @theTinMan Yeah, I had checked that out, but I was hoping to use the stock client library. Oh well! I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the alternate path is to run multiple instances of your client code, rather than try to do it with threads. People forget that an OS, like Linux or Mac OS, is designed to run multiple instances of code _IF_ the code is written to not step all over itself. Also, `map` is the wrong iterator. In the first example you should be using `each` because you're not returning something the result of the block and using it further.

Comment: @theTinMan I had actually thought about that too, but I couldn't see a good way to coordinate between processes so each request to get a page of recordings from Twilio would ask for a different page number, especially since the pages change as recordings are deleted. And I'm using `map` to return the thread and call `.join` on each one, so that the code doesn't complete until the the thread finishes running.